# Java Web Application to have Paypal Integration

Tags: java, paypal

I need to integrate paypal in my java web application to receive credit/debit card and paypal account payments.

I want it in such a way that I can manage the shopping cart at my website and then redirect the user to paypal for payment. After the user makes payment, I want to get the payment information back to my site so that I can maintain it in a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You will need a valid SSL certificate and you will need to integrate PayPal's libraries.  Take a look at the Payflow Pro API at this link.  I have worked with this software before - it is their most flexible option.

https://www.x.com/community/ppx/payflow_pro

Here is PayPal's new implementation of this technology:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro

Comment: @Mihir you'll have to learn Java, but the link should cover Paypal communication.  If you have any specific questions, feel free to ask it using the link at the top right of the page

Comment: i know java very well and the above link does not cover any applet specific information.